# Different data_size in replicated CouchDB databases

Tags: couchdb, database-replication

I'm testing with CouchDB using a test database that contains information about a discography.
The information about the database at a particular moment is the following:

```
{   
    "db_name":"pink_floyd",
    "doc_count":15,
    "doc_del_count":0,
    "update_seq":18,
    "purge_seq":0,
    "compact_running":false,
    "disk_size":249967,
    "data_size":223234,
    "instance_start_time":"1416540541575948",
    "disk_format_version":6,
    "committed_update_seq":18
}
```

Moments later I replied the database using curl:

```
curl -vH 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5984/_replicate -d ' {"source": "pink_floyd", "target": "pink_floyd_replica", "create_target": true, "continuous": true}'
```

And then (no one or nothing has used either in that time period), the information about replicated database is:

```
{
    "db_name":"pink_floyd_replica",
    "doc_count":15,
    "doc_del_count":0,
    "update_seq":15,
    "purge_seq":0,
    "compact_running":false,
    "disk_size":229487,
    "data_size":223198,
    "instance_start_time":"1416543583594649",
    "disk_format_version":6,
    "committed_update_seq":15
}
```

I can understand that "disk_size" field of the original database is greater than the same field of replicated database, but I cannot see why original "data_size" is greater than the new one. What fields and metadata are included is that amount? How is it calculated?

From [CouchDB docs](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/database/common.html#get--db):

- data_size (number) – Actual data size in bytes of the database data.
- disk_size (number) – Size in bytes of the data as stored on the disk. Views indexes are not included in the calculation.

... so what is *"Actual data size in bytes of the database data"*?

Comment: Could it be related to compression stage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data_size` is not only about the summary size of all stored documents. It's also about replication checkpoints (which are stored in _local docs), database file headers, security objects and some other properties. Replication only transfers documents (excluding _local ones) so it's not a surprise that the source and target `data_size` are different.

Comment: Thank you @Kxepal. So data isn't only actual data, it's metadata too. Do you know about the documentation where I can learn about how replication process is managed?

Comment: You can take a look on [replication protocol definition](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/replication/protocol.html).